# Parsing a timestamp with time zone

Tags: java, parsing, date, time, timestamp

I want to parse a timestamp given in this format `timestamp="2015-05-21 12:38:00Z"` using the class [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The problem is the `"Z"` in the end of `timestamp` which specifies the time zone. Unfortunately

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
```

doesn't do the job. It throws me:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-05-21 12:38:00Z"
```

If I use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

the string can be parsed but the time zone `"Z"` is neglected.

How can that problem be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `X` to indicate ISO 8601 time zone:

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX").parse("2015-05-21 12:38:00Z")`